# Can I replace the Windows bootloader with GRUB?

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, windows-7

I recently installed 12.04 via the Windows Installer, and I was wondering if it was possible to install Grub2 and use that instead of the Windows 7 boot-loader?

The Windows boot-loader works fine, however the Windows MSCOFIG application cannot see the partition (as it's code is not designed to detect Linux partition types (ext2, hpfs etc.)

I ran `fdisk -l` and it returned:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders, total 1465149168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x10a444cc

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848  1416081407   707937280    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3      1416081408  1465147391    24532992   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot use GRUB2 to replace NTLDR because GRUB2 cannot load itself from an  NTFS partition.

You should understand that installing Ubuntu via Windows does NOT create it's own partition, but creates a flat file on the NTFS partition which is loop-mounted and then formatted as ext3. Thats why this partition will *only* be detected by tools running from within the Ubuntu install -- neither Windows nor a LiveUSB/LiveCD will detect it.